# XSLT - Set attribute with value of child

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to set the attribute of the parent based on the value of the first child.
I am using XSLT 1.0.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>text...text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>text...text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

should be transformed to:

```xml
<div>
    <div data-type="alphanumeric">
        <span>text...text</span>
    </div>
    <div data-type="numeric">
        <span>text...text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me how i can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are those the only two options: `alphanumeric` or `numeric`? If not, please provide a complete set of rules how to determine the value of data-type.

Comment: yes only this two - if is a number ( [0-9]* ) is should take numeric, else alphanumeric.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[span]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="data-type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="translate(span[1], '0123456789', '')">alphanumeric</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>numeric</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this selects `numeric` only when the value contains digits only; IOW, a value of `<span>0.1</span>` will be tagged as `alphanumeric`.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
<xsl:when test="number(span[1])=number(span[1])">numeric</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>alphanumeric</xsl:otherwise>
```

which will tag any *number* as `numeric`.